# Join based on condition and filter by timerange & limit to just the first row in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have relation A, relation B. For each row in A, might have more than one mapping in relation B.

Say:

```
A = (id1, type, location, gender, startDateTime)
B = (id2, type, location, gender, registerStartDateTime, registerEndDateTime, value)
```

I need to join A & B on (type, location & gender) and when (startDateTime > registerStartDateTime) and (startDateTime < registerEndDateTime)

This join may return multiple rows from B with different values. I want to pick just the first returned row and finally output.

```
output = Join A by (type, location, gender), B by (type, location, gender)
```

How to add the date time range condition to the above join?
How to limit to only one row from B when the join is executed?

In SQL:

```
SELECT 
a.id, b.value
FROM
    a, b
WHERE
    a.type = b.type
        AND a.location = b.location
        AND a.gender = b.gender
        AND a.startDateTime between b.registerStartDateTime and b.registerEndDateTime 
limit 1;
```

How to do the same in Pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
A = (id1, type, location, gender, startDateTime)
B = (id2, type, location, gender, registerStartDateTime, registerEndDateTime, value)

output = Join A by (type, location, gender), B by (type, location, gender)

filteroutput = filter output by (startDateTime > registerStartDateTime) AND (startDateTime < registerEndDateTime);

/*sortoutput = order filteroutput by  startDateTime ; 

  limitoutput = limit sortoutput 1 ;
*/

  limitoutput = limit filteroutput 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out. What if the the DateTime fields were bytearrays? How to use them in the filter condition?